# Remove shared Windows folder from WSL?

Tags: windows, wsl2

By default, WSL contains `/mnt/c/Users/UserName`, which is a share to the Windows drive.

I'd like to close that link between the two operating systems,because it's dangerous for `rm` command in WSL to be able to to affect Windows files.

How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By *"close the link between two os system"*, if you mean to disable
automatically mounting the Windows' partitions, then:

- `sudo -e /etc/wsl.conf` (this will use your system's default editor)
- Add the following:

  ```
  [automount]
  enabled=false
  ```
- Exit your WSL distribution
- From PowerShell:

  ```
  wsl --shutdown
  ```
- Restart WSL
  From [How to close wsl2 and windows user sharing folder?](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5870).

It worked for me as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]